# How to get the 'end' resolution after an animation in OL3?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

With [OpenLayers 3.20](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/releases/tag/v3.20.0), the `change:resolution` event is fired multiple times while an animation is progress on the `ol.View`.  Prior to that version, it used to be fired only once.  That was also true for `change:center`.

My question is this: is there a way to know when an animation begins (that would be the hook I would like to bind some sort of event listener) and from there get the resolution at the end of the animation?  Basically, I want to know if it's possible to get the previous behaviour prior to 3.20.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a way if you're using `ol.View#animate` — use a callback when the animation ends:

```
map.getView().animate({
  center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([37.6178, 55.7517]),
  zoom: 5
}, animateCallback);

function animateCallback (complete) {
  if (complete) {
    console.log(map.getView().getResolution());
    console.log(map.getView().getZoom());
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/jr0d7dLb/

Comment: That works if I the animation is done manually, but what if I want to hook when the user uses the zoom controls, or the mouse wheel?

Comment: Indeed, only animations started by you. Well it looks like it could be an addition to the library.