# Openlayers on view fit animation ends

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using openlayers 6.5.

I have:

```
/* Set the features to fill the map */
var extent = ol.extent.createEmpty();
for(var county_id in map['map_internal_data'])
{
    ol.extent.extend(
        extent,
        map['openlayers_features']['counties'][county_id].getGeometry().getExtent()
    );
}
map['openlayers'].getView().fit(
    extent,
    {
        size: map['openlayers'].getSize(),
        padding: [25, 10, 25, 10],
        duration:1000
    }
);

/* I need to call a function here, but only after above animation ends */
function_after_above_animation_ends();
```

The above code takes geometry of counties and zoom the map until the counties fill the map. As you see, there is an animation setting there: `duration:1000`.

What I need is to call a function after fit ends (after animation ends).

I can use `setTimeout` `1000`, but I don't think this is the properly way to do this.

I need something like a `promise`...

Comment: Does it help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41263869/how-to-get-the-end-resolution-after-an-animation-in-ol3

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work for `fit` :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fit has a `callback` option https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_View-View.html#fit

```
map['openlayers'].getView().fit(
    extent,
    {
        size: map['openlayers'].getSize(),
        padding: [25, 10, 25, 10],
        duration:1000,
        callback: myFunction
    }
);
```